# python-3.5.1: unable to 'make' on mipsel

Tags: python, python-3.x, mips, python-3.5, mips32

I am trying to install python-3.5.1 on mipsel. Initially while doing 'make' it gave me syntax error in graminit file, so i gave it the path of graminit.h of another python-3.5.1 (which was compiled for ubuntu 14.04 or say x86 platform).Later same happened for my importlib module (again i did the same).And now it is giving me syntax invalid as:-

```
  Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Lib/site.py", line 72, in <module>
    import os
  File "./Lib/os.py", line 666, in <module>
    from _collections_abc import MutableMapping
  File "./Lib/_collections_abc.py", line 56
    async def _coro(): pass
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
make: *** [sharedmods] Error 1
```

Comment: Please add all the exports and configure flags which you used.

Comment: Maybe it might be prudent to address the initial error instead of ignoring it. Did you diff the gram init.h that had the error and the one that's ok? It's a generated file so it stands to reason it would be different for different platforms.

Comment: Or somehow the wrong Python is running this? `async def` was introduced in 3.5.  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/

Comment: yes , aynsc was introduced in python 3.5 and even i am using the same one python-3.5.1. and exports and configure are as:-

Comment: export CC=/opt/buildroot-gcc342/mipsel-linux-gcc
export CFLAGS=-I/opt/buildroot-gcc342/include
export CC=/opt/buildroot-gcc342/bin/mipsel-linux-gcc
   export CC=/opt/buildroot-gcc342/bin/mipsel-linux-gcc
   export LDFLAGS=-L/opt/buildroot-gcc342/lib
   export CC=/opt/buildroot-gcc342/bin/mipsel-linux-a    
   export AR=/opt/buildroot-gcc342/bin/mipsel-linux-ar
   export RANLIB=/opt/buildroot-gcc342/bin/mipsel-linux-ranlib 
   export HOSTPGEN=/home/palak/Downloads/python3/Python-          3.5.1_pc/Parser/pgen 
   export CXX=/opt/buildroot-gcc342/bin/mipsel-linux-g++

Comment: CONFIG_SITE=config.site ./configure --host=mipsel-linux --build=mipsel --prefix=/home/palak/Downloads/python3/Python-3.5.1/AL2/ --disable-ipv6 --enable-shared